# SAS CSV export has an unwanted leading comma in each row

Tags: csv, sas, export-to-csv

I'm new to SAS and am struggling to export data to CSV. My code successfully exports a file but it has a leading comma on each non-header row that creates a misalignment.

I feel like I am missing something obvious and could really use some help. Thank you!

```
data _null_;
file "/export.csv";
set "/table" (keep= field1 field2 'field 3'n);
if _n_ = 1 then 
    do;       /* write header row */
        put "field1" 
            ',' 
            "field2"
            ','
            "field3";
    end;
    do;
        put (_all_) (','); 
    end;
run;
```

My output ends up looking like this...

field1,field2,field3,

,x ,y ,z

,a ,b ,c

,d ,e ,f...

or

| Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | x | y | z |
|  | a | b | c |
|  | d | e | f |

Comment: Check out the DSD FILE statement option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to already know the variable names (since you have hard coded the header line) then just modify the PUT statement to not insert the extra comma.

```
put field1 (field2 'field 3'n) (',');
```

But really you should just tell SAS you are writing a delimited file by using the DSD option.

```
/* write header row */
data _null_;
  file "/export.csv";
  put "field1,field2,field 3";
run;


/* Add the actual data */
data _null_;
  file "/export.csv" dsd mod ;
  set table;
  put field1 field2 'field 3'n ;
run;
```

If you don't actually know the variable names in advance then just ask SAS to generate them for you.

```
/* write header row */
proc transpose data=table(obs=0) out=names;
  var _all_;
run;
data _null_;
  file "/export.csv" dsd;
  set names;
  put _name_ @;
run;

/* Add the actual data */
data _null_;
  file "/export.csv" dsd mod ;
  set table ;
  put (_all_) (+0);
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for the thorough reply. This method provides the most flexibility to my needs.

Answer (score 2):

Use `proc export` instead. It'll save you a lot of time and effort compared to coding a manual export of .csv.

```
proc export 
    data = table(keep=field1 field2 field3)
    file = '/export.csv'
    dbms = csv
    replace;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a straightforward way to export. I'll use this method when renaming the columns is not an issue (which was not clear from my post).

Comment: You can rename columns before exporting as well using dataset options. `proc export data=foo(rename=(field1=new_name1 field2=new_name2)) ... `

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up! That's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A general version using my second favorite CALL routine.

```
data _null_;
   file log ls=256 dsd; /*change LOG to your file*/
   set sashelp.heart;
   if _n_ eq 1 then link names;
   put (_all_)(:);
   return;
names:
   length _name_ $32;
   do while(1);
      call vnext(_name_);
      if _name_ eq '_name_' then leave;
      put _name_ @;
      end;
   put;
   return;
   run;
```

Comment: Thank you! *checks username*... yeah, checks out.

Answer (score 0):

In the interim, I had Magoo'd may way into a method that works, too, but these are all good answers.

I used the dsd file statement option.

```
data _null_;
file "/export.csv"; dsd delimiter=",";
set "/table" (keep= field1 field2 'field 3'n);
if _n_ = 1 then 
    do;       /* write header row */
        put "field1" 
            ',' 
            "field2"
            ','
            "field3";
    end;
    do;
        put (_all_) (+0); 
    end;
run;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

One more option, which does work if renaming the columns.

- ODS CSV
- LABELS option to print labels instead of variable names which allows for renaming. Also supports changing/applying formats while exporting.

```
ods csv file='/home/fkhurshed/demo.csv';

proc print data=sashelp.class label noobs;
label age= 'Age (years)' sex = 'Sex' weight = 'Weight (lbs)' height = 'Height (inches)';
run;

ods csv close;
```